# SceneKit CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -11

Tags: macos, cocoa, scenekit

I'm in the progress of trying out SceneKit, and one of the things I want to do is load scenes from COLLADA files. This works well, however, the textures are not loading, and when loading the files, I get the following error:

```
<Error>: ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithURL CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -11.
```

I believe that part of the problem here is the way I organise the files in my app bundle — a file called `Textures.bundle` holding all textures, organised by category, and a `Models.bundle` that holds the COLLADA files:

[image: xcode file tree]

I have written classes to get the path of files in categories (folders) of the bundle, which return the correct path. Even Xcode can get the files right, and load the same COLLADA files properly, even going to the point of recognising the images in the Textures bundle:

[image: xcode COLLADA preview]

The texture location is set as "relative to DAE document," yielding the following (correct) path: `../../Textures.bundle/ModelTextures/Computer/motherboard_motherboard.jpg`

In the app, then, it is rendered like this:

[image: render output]

Any ideas?

Comment: First question, do you get consistent results between the Xcode Editor, Preview and QuickLook (pressing space in Finder) for the file or does one of those have this problem? Second question, of you inspect the geometry objects in the Xcode editor, does some of them have color values along with the vertices and normals?

Comment: Xcode, Preview and QuickLook all render the model correctly. The geometry does use several materials, only one of which has a texture and the rest are solid colours, but none are white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that Xcode and the runtime use different algorithms to find resources for Scene Kit, so it’s not too surprising it works in one and not the other. (The Xcode one obviously needs to be able to look through all your source, the runtime one is much more specific about where it will look.)

That said, can you post what your application’s Resources directory looks like? Like, if you go into it and do an `ls -FR`, do you see the structure you’d expect? Everything is copied in OK?

Also, if that’s the same model, you’ve got more problems than just your textures not loading. I mean, that looks totally whack. Are you doing something else to the files you load?

Comment: When checking the compiled product, I do indeed see the folder structure I expect, as follows: http://pastebin.com/4pJsgqzP

As for the model looking whacky when loaded at runtime, that's caused because I haven't set up a camera properly. I'm loading in specific nodes from the COLLADA files using an `SCNSceneSource` after decompressing the model from disk and adding them to an existing scene, and it doesn't always work right.

Comment: I did some more testing, and checking the `SCNMaterial` of the model once it's loaded yields an NSImage sized 0x0 pixels as its diffuse.

Comment: I had a discussion once with the team about this, because we were running into issues. I can’t remember exactly the outcome, but my memory is that the way incomplete paths are interpreted is different when you’re running the program vs. when you’re in Xcode. Maybe try making the resource paths be relative to the Resources folder? Like, eliminate the “../..” part?

Comment: …Never mind, I'm an idiot and shouldn't code in the middle of class. Eliminating the "../.." part did the trick!